# Angular 6 wait for subscribe to finish

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have function like:

```js
getNumber(value) {
    this.myService.getApi(value).subscribe(data => {
        this.myVariable = data;
    });
}
```

And I am calling that function in other function as follows :

```js
set() {
    if (this.value == 1) {
        this.getNumber(firstNumber)
        this.newVariable = this.myVariable;
    } else {
        this.getNumber(secondNumber)
        this.newVariabe = this.myVariable + 1;
    }
};
```

`this.value` is getting from other function. The problem is that `this.newVariable` is empty. I'm sure this is because the subscribe hasn't finished before I try to access `this.Variable`

Is there any way to wait for the subscribe to finish before I do anything else?

Comment: `getNumber` should return the Observable, and you should subscribe to it in the "other" function, when you need the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return an Observable from getNumber and subscribe to it.

You can also add pipe to getNumber so it will handle storing data and also return an Observable to subscribe to.

```
getNumber(value) {
    return this.myService.getApi(value).pipe(tap(data => {
        this.myVariable = data;
    }));
}
```

And in your set method

```
set() {
    if (this.value == 1) {
      this.getNumber(firstNumber).subscribe(() => {
        this.newVariable = this.myVariable;
      });
    }
    else {
      this.getNumber(secondNumber).subscribe(() => {
        this.newVariabe = this.myVariable + 1;
      });
   }
};
```