# Angular 8 > I get data correctly from Http.Subscribe but then is Undefined

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, service, httprequest

A simple Http.Get, and I missing something but I don't realize what is't.

```
this.http.get<Reserve[]>(this.url).
subscribe(result => {
    this.reserves = result;
        console.log('Data from source:' , result , 'Data when load:' , this.reserves)
    },
    error => console.error('Loading reserve error', error));

console.log('Data after Load', this.reserves);
```

Console results indicate that the data has been actually capture (Data from source and Data when load):

[Console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Qcq.png)

```
Data from source: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, restaurantId: 1, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-17T21:00:00", ranking: 1, …}1: {id: 2, restaurantId: 2, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-18T20:00:00", ranking: 1, …}2: {id: 3, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-20T19:00:00", ranking: 4, …}3: {id: 4, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-21T20:00:00", ranking: 5, …}4: {id: 5, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-17T21:00:00", ranking: 2, …}length: 5__proto__: Array(0) 
Data when load: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, restaurantId: 1, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-17T21:00:00", ranking: 1, …}1: {id: 2, restaurantId: 2, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-18T20:00:00", ranking: 1, …}2: {id: 3, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-20T19:00:00", ranking: 4, …}3: {id: 4, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-21T20:00:00", ranking: 5, …}4: {id: 5, restaurantId: 4, restaurant: {…}, dateReserve: "2020-05-17T21:00:00", ranking: 2, …}length: 5__proto__: Array(0)
```

But 'Data after Load' is **UNDEFINED**

Comment: 'Data after Load' actually  gets prints first, before the response is  obtained in the subscription .

Comment: An http request is an asynchronous function. The 'Data after Load' isn't going to wait for the async function to complete. So of course it will be undefined.

Comment: The variable `this.reserves` is assigned asynchronously. It **cannot** be accessed synchronously. Any statements that depend on it directly should be inside the subscription. In other words, you need to subscribe to the observable where the `this.reserves` is required.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Call Your Method Inside Subscribe To Do What You Want to Do After Load Data:

[Angular 2+ wait for subscribe to finish to update/access variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50951868/2126355)

```
 export class myClass {
  myVariable: any;

  myFunction() {
    this.myService.getApi().subscribe(data => {
      this.myVariable = data;
      this.update()
    });

    this.update()
  }

  update(){
    console.log(this.myVariable);
  }
}
```

Or Return Obsevable To Subscribe EveryWhere You Want to Use Result:

[Angular 6 wait for subscribe to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888794/2126355)

```
getNumber(value) {
    return this.myService.getApi(value).pipe(tap(data => {
        this.myVariable = data;
    }));
}
```

And in your set method

```
set() {
    if (this.value == 1) {
      this.getNumber(firstNumber).subscribe(() => {
        this.newVariable = this.myVariable;
      });
    }
    else {
      this.getNumber(secondNumber).subscribe(() => {
        this.newVariabe = this.myVariable + 1;
      });
   }
};
```

Or Use await to wait until result is ready:

[Angular 2+ wait for method / observable to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967652/2126355)

```
  async isAuthenticated(){
     const response = await this.http.get('/login/authenticated').toPromise();
     return response.json();
  }

async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.loginStatus = await this.loginService.isAuthenticated();

    console.log("LOGGED IN STATUS: " + this.loginStatus);

    if (this.loginStatus == true){
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/layout/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because it is an async method that will not wait to get a response from the server.
try to use async/await or print the value inside then block

```
    this.http.get<Reserve[]>(this.url).subscribe(result => {
        this.reserves = result;
        console.log('Data from source:' , result , 'Data when load:' , this.reserves)
        console.log('Data after Load', this.reserves);
    },
    error => console.error('Loading reserve error', error));
```

Comment: Thanks, for that point on everything is going great.